# Paley-Winer theorem

Tags: fourier-series, functional-equations, convolution, nonlinear-system

This problem is Theorem 2 from an old paper "ASYMPTOTIC BEHAVIOR OP SOLUTIONS OF
NONLINEAR VOLTERRA EQUATIONS" by R. K. Miller. Consider a scalar equation
\begin{equation}
x(t)=f(t)-\int_0^ta(t-s)x(s)ds.
\end{equation}
The theorem says

Suppose $a(t)\in L_1(0,\infty)$, $f(t)$ is bounded, measurable and tends to a limit $f_0$ as $t\rightarrow\infty$. For each such $f$ the solution of the scalar equation is bounded and tend to the limit
\begin{equation}
x(t)\rightarrow x_0=f_0/(1+\int_0^{\infty}a(s)ds) ~\text{as} ~t\rightarrow\infty
\end{equation}
if and only if when $Re(u)\geq 0$ one has
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{\infty}a(t)e^{-ut}dt\neq-1
\end{equation}

The author gave reference "Soc. 68 (1962), 323-329.
4. R. E. A. C. Paley and N. Wiener, Fourier transforms in the complex domain,
Amer. Math.Soc.Colloq.Publ. Vol.XIX,Amer. Math. Soc, Providence, R. I., 1934", which is not available to me.

I do not understand how this theorem comes from, any kind of help is appreciated, THANK YOU!

Comment: I applied laplace transform and have\begin{equation} X(s)=\frac{F(s)}{1+A(s)}\end{equation}, then applying final value theorem, I have \begin{equation} x(\infty)=\lim_{s\rightarrow 0}sF(s)/(1+A(s)) \end{equation}. Since $a(t)\in L_1$, $A(0)<\infty$.

Comment: Since $a(t)\in L_1$, $A(0)<\infty$. But $\lim_{s\rightarrow 0}sF(s)$ I can not calculate. Some help please?

Comment: $\lim_{s\rightarrow 0}sF(s)=\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}f(t)=f_0$, problem solved.